# How do I identify which dataspace was left open and not closed in HDF5 fortran interface?

Tags: fortran, hdf5

While using the fortran interface for HDF5, I created a file using:

```
      CALL h5fcreate_f(filename(1:len_file)                               &
   &          , H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F, file_id, error)
```

and closed datapace/datasets with

```
       CALL h5dclose_f(dataspace_id, error)
       CALL h5sclose_f(dataspace_id, error)
```

finally closed the file with

```
       CALL h5fclose_f(file_id, error)
```

But the file is not being written immediately. I suspect this is because some dataset/dataspace is still open. Is there a routine to identify or close all open datasets/dataspaces. so the file can be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the number of open identifiers using `H5Fget_obj_count_f`.  You can query the open identifiers themselves using `H5Fget_obj_ids`.  The `H5I*` procedures then let you query the nature of those open identifiers.

For example:

```
PROGRAM test_hdf5_get_obj_ids
  USE HDF5
  IMPLICIT NONE
  
  INTEGER(HID_T) :: file_id
  INTEGER(HID_T) :: group_id
  INTEGER(HID_T) :: space_id
  INTEGER(HID_T) :: set_id
  INTEGER :: error
  
  REAL, ALLOCATABLE, TARGET :: data(:)
  
  data = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
  
  CALL H5open_f(error)
  IF (error < 0) ERROR STOP 'H5open_f failed'
  
  CALL H5Fcreate_f(  &
      NAME='test_hdf5.h5',  &
      ACCESS_FLAGS=H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F,  &   ! HDF5 docs dummy argument spelling error.
      FILE_ID=file_id,  &
      HDFERR=error )
  IF (error < 0) ERROR STOP 'H5Fcreate_f failed'
  
  CALL H5Gcreate_f(  &
      LOC_ID=file_id,  &
      NAME='Group',  &
      GRP_ID=group_id,  &
      HDFERR=error )
  IF (error < 0) ERROR STOP 'H5Gcreate_f failed'
  
  CALL H5Screate_simple_f(  &
      RANK=1,  &
      DIMS=SHAPE(data, KIND=HSIZE_T),  &
      SPACE_ID=space_id,  &
      HDFERR=error )
  IF (error < 0) ERROR STOP 'H5Screate_simple_f failed'
  
  CALL H5Dcreate_f(  &
      LOC_ID=group_id,  &
      NAME='Dataset',  &
      TYPE_ID=H5T_NATIVE_REAL,  &
      SPACE_ID=space_id,  &
      DSET_ID=set_id,  &
      HDFERR=error )
  IF (error < 0) ERROR STOP 'H5Dcreate_f failed'
  
  CALL H5Dwrite_f(  &
      DSET_ID=set_id,  &
      MEM_TYPE_ID=H5T_NATIVE_REAL,  &
      BUF=C_LOC(data),  &
      HDFERR=error )
  IF (error < 0) ERROR STOP 'H5Dwrite_f failed'
  
  CALL H5Dclose_f(set_id, error)
  CALL H5Sclose_f(space_id, error)
  ! CALL H5Gclose_f(group_id, error)    ! Oops - forgot this one.
  CALL H5Fclose_f(file_id, error)
  
  BLOCK
    INTEGER(SIZE_T) :: obj_count
    
    CALL H5Fget_obj_count_f(  &
        FILE_ID=INT(H5F_OBJ_ALL_F, HID_T),  &
        OBJ_TYPE=H5F_OBJ_ALL_F,  &
        OBJ_COUNT=obj_count,  &
        HDFERR=error )
    IF (error < 0) ERROR STOP 'H5Fget_obj_count_f failed'
    
    PRINT "(I0,' open identifiers')", obj_count
    
    BLOCK
      INTEGER(HID_T) :: obj_ids(obj_count)
      INTEGER :: i
      INTEGER :: type
      CHARACTER(:), ALLOCATABLE :: type_text
      
      CALL H5Fget_obj_ids_f(  &
        FILE_ID=INT(H5F_OBJ_ALL_F, HID_T),  &
        OBJ_TYPE=H5F_OBJ_ALL_F,  &
        MAX_OBJS=obj_count,  &
        OBJ_IDS=obj_ids,  &
        HDFERR=error )
      IF (error < 0) ERROR STOP 'H5F_get_obj_ids_f failed'
      
      DO i = 1, SIZE(obj_ids)
        CALL H5Iget_type_f(obj_ids(i), type, error)
        IF (error < 0) ERROR STOP 'H5Iget_type_f failed'
        
        IF (type == H5I_FILE_F) THEN
          type_text = 'file'
        ELSE IF (type == H5I_GROUP_F) THEN
          type_text = 'group'
        ELSE IF (type == H5I_DATATYPE_F) THEN
          type_text = 'datatype'
        ELSE IF (type == H5I_DATASPACE_F) THEN
          type_text = 'dataspace'
        ELSE IF (type == H5I_DATASET_F) THEN
          type_text = 'dataset'
        ELSE IF (type == H5I_ATTR_F) THEN
          type_text = 'attribute'
        ELSE
          type_text = 'unknown'
        END IF
        PRINT "('Open identifier ',I0,' is a ',A)", i, type_text
      END DO
    END BLOCK
  END BLOCK
  
  CALL H5close_f(error)
END PROGRAM test_hdf5_get_obj_ids
```